# Docker-compose mongoose

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker, and I'm trying the simplest of setups with docker-compose, but don't succeed to connect to Mongodb.

My docker-compose.local.yaml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  posts-api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
    ports:
      - "6820:6820"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.5
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
    command: mongod --port 27018
```

My Docker file:

```
FROM node:7.8.0
MAINTAINER Livefeed 'project.livefeed@gmail.com'

RUN mkdir /app
VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN eval rm -rf node_modules && \
yarn

ADD server.js .
RUN mkdir config src
ADD config config/
ADD src src/

EXPOSE 6820
EXPOSE 27018

CMD yarn run local
```

In server.js I try to connect with:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27018');
```

I also tried:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodb:27018');
```

To run docker-compose:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yaml up --build
```

And I receive the error:

```
connection error: { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27018] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27018]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Tamas, yes I have done this in my Docker.local.yaml file, I'll add it to the description

Comment: sorry I meant services: mongo: image: 'mongo:3.5' ports: '27018:27017'.

Comment: @Tamas I would like to run at port 27018, because I want to run a different mongo instance per microservice

Comment: But you'd still need to link the mongodb port to another port. If you want to change the default listening port of mongodb, you need to tell it so by 'command: mongod --port 27018' when you define your 'mongodb' service.

Comment: @Tamas Added it, but I get the same result...

Comment: Does mongodb://mongodb:27018 work when using mongoose.connect()?

Comment: @Tamas, nope... same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146458/discussion-between-tamas-and-kim-gysen).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In server.js use `mongodb` instead of `localhost`:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodb:27018');
```

Because containers in the same network can communicate using their service name.

Bear in mind that each container and your host have their own localhost. Each localhost is a different `host`: container A, container B, your host (each one has its own network interface).

---

Edit:

Be sure to get your mongo up:

```
docker-compose logs mongodb
docker-compose ps
```

Sometimes it doesn't get up because of disk space.

---

Edit 2:

With newer versions of mongo, you need to specify to listen to all interfaces too:

```
command: mongod --port 27018 --bind_ip_all
```

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunately, with the exact same result... But with the depends_on, or links, shouldn't it work? I'll update the question details.

Comment: Indeed, you don't need both. With `version: "2"` or 3, you get your containers in a docker network so they are able to connect using their service names. (links and depends_on add dependency information only)

Comment: when I try this, it says: `Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?` I use a file named `docker-compose.local.yaml', according to the environment (I use config.js). Docker ps -a shows mongo:3.5 being up 6 minutes. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you should add `links` option in your config. Like this:

```
ports:
  - "6820:6820"
depends_on:
  - mongodb
links:
  - mongodb
```

**update**

As I promised

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    pm2:
      image: keymetrics/pm2-docker-alpine:6
      restart: always
      container_name: pm2
      volumes:
        - ./pm2:/app
      links:
        - redis_db
        - db
      environment:
        REDIS_CONNECTION_STRING: redis://redis_db:6379

    nginx:
      image: firesh/nginx-lua
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      ports:
        - 80:80
      links:
        - pm2

        s3: # mock for development
      image: lphoward/fake-s3:latest

    redis_db:
      container_name: redis_db
      image: redis
      ports:
        - 6379:6379

    db: # for scorebig-syncer
      image: mysql:5.7
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
```

Comment: Links are considered deprecated. Use docker's DNS and networks to connect containers together as Robert suggests.